# Powershell Auto Service Restart

Tags: powershell, service, restart

I have a problem on prtg probe server on one specific server. 
In this Server, cpu usage hits 90% and need to restart because of prtg service. 
How can I restart the prtg service automatically when the cpu usage hit 90%?

I was thinking of creating a script with a condition but couldn't complete it.

`-Set-Service [service name] -startuptype automatic`

Comment: Take a look at this post: [HOW TO TRIGGER AN EMAIL ALERT FROM WINDOWS PERFORMANCE MONITOR](https://clusteringformeremortals.com/2018/10/18/step-by-step-how-to-trigger-an-email-alert-from-windows-performance-monitor/).  It shows how to csend an email based on a Perfmon alert, but you could modify it to restart a service or some other task.

Comment: @boxdog thank you for advice but how can I associate when server's cpu hit to 90% and I need to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell 5.x you can use `Get-Counter` to get CPU usage. Try the following on the server to check:

```
$peridiocallyChecks = {
   # Check if logging source is available, if not add it
   if (!(Get-EventLog -Source "CPU supervision" -LogNameApplication)){
       New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "CPU supervision"
   }

   $cpuUsage = [double] (Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue)

   if ($cpuUsage -gt 90) {
       Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "CPU supervision" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "CPU usage is $cpuUsage. Going to stop service"
       Stop-Service "yourServiceName"
       # Some cooldown time for the service to shutdown
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
       Start-Service "yourServiceName"
       Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "CPU supervision" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "Restarted service"
   }
}

# Trigger every hour
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At "9/21/2012 0am" -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hour 12) -RepetitionDuration ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)

Register-ScheduledJob -Name "CPUCheck" -Trigger $trigger -Scriptblock $peridiocallyChecks
```

Check following links regarding jobs:

- [Introduction to PS Jobs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs/)
- [New-JobTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/new-jobtrigger?view=powershell-5.1)
- [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, I am so grateful. I am going to try it.

Comment: I have some noob questions, where can I see the this logs and which date should I give because like I gave today or other dates it is giving error. Also, how can I specify the cpu from yourServiceName? Thank you for understanding.

Comment: The logs are written to the Windows event log. Do you need the CPU of the whole server, or do you need the CPU of the service you want to restart?

Comment: I looked everywhere in Windows event log and in task schedular->microsoft->powershell->schedulejobs but I couldn't find. If it is possible could you please give little bit more information?

Comment: I've uddate my answer, forgot to add `New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "CPU supervision"`. You should be able to retrieve the event logs via `Get-EventLog -Source "CPU supervision" -LogName Application`

Comment: I added to Get-EventLog -Source "CPU supervision" -LogName Application but it is giving error. Do you have any solution? and I still couldn't find the logs in windows event log or task scheduler.

Comment: Maybe you have to call `New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "CPU supervision"` once with admin rights.

Comment: yes I tried I have admin rights but still it's same.

Comment: Are you sure it is saving in windows event log?

Comment: I tried it on my local host, it worked. Just try it on your local machine.

Comment: okay, thank you so much for helping. I am so grateful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

to get CPU usage of PRTG you can use following powershell line

```
Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| where {$_.InstanceName -match "prtg" }
```

you can then compare it with your limit (90%) and decide if you want to run following command in powershell

```
restart-service PRTG
```

That would be the answer, and now my suggestion to your situation

- restarting probe is never solution to high CPU load - try to add more CPU if possible
- reduce amount of sensors
- identify long running sensors or CPU heavy sensors and optimize them or remove them/replace them with lightweight alternative
- add another probe to different machine if adding CPU(s) or above points are not  an option - this way you can split sensor to two probes